# How can I reduce spell casting duration

Tags: dark-souls-2

Like said in the title, I'm looking for a list of all the solutions to speed up the casting of my spells.

I have found the `Clear Bluestone Ring` but i want to reduce more the casting duration.

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/DarkSouls2/comments/21txwe/buildwiki_help_stat_bonus_casting_speed_and/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple ways to increase casting speed.

1. Wear the [Clear Bluestone Ring](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Clear+Bluestone+Ring) (or +1, +2 variants)
2. Raise your attunement, intelligent, or faith stats. ([Attunement has a larger effect per point](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Casting+Speed))
3. Wear armor that increases casting speed. [Some listed here.](http://www.reddit.com/r/DarkSouls2/comments/21txwe/buildwiki_help_stat_bonus_casting_speed_and/)

Answer (score 1):

There's two things I did for a quick boost.

1) You can use two bonfire asthetics before the `Skeleton Lords` boss (it's still very easy) and unlock the Clear Bluestone Ring + 2. This is a quick way to speed up spell casting, but the asthetic carries into NG+ so that section will be NG+++! So be wary in advance of using this.

2) Go to the `Shaded Woods` and find the Lion Mage Set.

[Lion Mage Set:](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Lion+Mage+Set)

•Found in a chest in the Shaded Woods. Near the path to the boss fight, there is a petrified Lion blocking a doorway in a ruined building. Unpetrify him using a Fragrant Branch of Yore. Beware, there a many curse pots in the room with the chest. Cursebite Ring is recommended, as well as breaking the pots at range. The chest will be found behind the pots. The set will be found, as well as another Fragrant Branch of Yore

•Note: The entire set can be retrieved without using a Fragrant Branch of Yore. One can get the set by jumping while running into the crack in the wall right behind the iron chest left of the petrified Lion, aim for the top right of the crack to do so successfully.

Lion Mage Stats:

◦Each piece of the set increases Cast Speed by 5.2% rounded DOWN to the nearest whole value.
◦Effects are compounded by the Clear Bluestone Ring.
◦Effects are compounded by wearing multiple pieces of the set.